# How to list all files with Finder Comment using unix?

Tags: unix, spotlight

How i can get path of all files, folders which has Finder comment and also the comment.

Like this:
/path/here/file.txt TAB finder comment is here
/path4/here2/folder TAB finder comment is here

I could first use this to find all items with comment:

```
mdfind kMDItemFinderComment == '*'
```

And then find the comments:

```
mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment pathhere
```

But is there a way to get all in single command?

Comment: Create a permanent alias for the combined commands, without including the path course.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
 find . -xattrname com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment \
        -exec printf %s\\t {} \; \
        -exec mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment -raw {} \; \
        -exec echo \;
```

Breaking this down a little:

- `find` looks through the current directory (`.`) (and everything "below") for files with an extended attribute (`-xattrname`) called `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment`.
- As it finds each file:

  - the first `-exec` argument uses `printf` to print out the file path and a tab (`\t`) character.
  - The second `-exec` runs `mdls` to read the actual comment.
  - The third `-exec` just prints out a newline (`\n`) character.

Note that the `find` command is recursive, so this solution will look through subdirectories as well.

If you require absolute paths then use `` find `pwd` `` instead of `find .`

Answer (score 0):

No - you'll need to script the two commands together and loop over the list of files. It's a bit of a chore since you'll need to handle spaces in file names and unicode characters as well as potentially finding 100,000 files that match and avoid rolling your variable over the max length.

For small searches, you could probably stuff all the results in one variable and pipe things together, but that's liable to break under foreseeable real world uses.